# Calculate Surface area of a Table using computer vision

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to calculate the area of the table surface with the help of stereo camera particularly Zed 2i camera. But the problem is table can be anywhere in the picture may be near to the camera (that means covering more pixels of the image) or away from the camera (covering less pixels of the image) and I need to calculate the area of the table approximately same every time irrespective of its position in image. How can I achieve this? Any suggestions?

What algorithm I can implement to get this?

A reference of table can be found here:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. The surface of the table is always the same. You mean the surface of the projection? Just detect the 4 corners and compute the are of the resulting trapezoid.

Comment: I will elaborate my question. I have different flat surfaces with different lengths and breadths lets say  several tables with different lengths, breadths and heights. These flat surfaces can be 17 meters long as well with varying other two dimensions (breadth and height). I have my camera installed like this we can see in the image (at some angle) and camera is fixed. I want to calculate the surface area of the flat surface of the table. moreover, table can be sometimes at 2 meter distance from camera and sometimes it can be 10 meters away from the camera. I want to have similar area all time

Comment: " I want to have similar area all time"  How tables with different breadths and lengths give similar areas? It doens't make any sense. It's completely unclear what you want. You should edit your question and make an example of the inputs and expected outputs. Also you want the areas in pixels? Because to convert pixels to meters you need some reference object of known size to do the conversion. Or have the camera calibration parameters. For example, just with the posted picture it's impossible to know the area of the table. You need more information.

Comment: Aah Sorry, I want to say that If we test with only one table and place it at different positions in the picture. Then, i want to estimate the area of that particular table approximately same. And yes, I want the area in physical units like centimeters^2. I hope this time it's clear.

Comment: to convert pixels to meters you need some reference object of known size to do the conversion.

Comment: My follow up thought is where should i place the reference object? Again if the reference object is near to the camera then it contains more pixels and if its far away then it contains less pixels. So, what should be the right place for it?

Comment: I have length and breadth. But the problem is the camera isn't horizontal while you standing.. Here is link: https://imgur.com/a/EYTvvEC

Comment: I don't see any code or any data from your stereo camera. a *single view* does not contain enough information to give you the answer you seek. -- if you don't know what's "table" in the picture, get some AI model to give you a semantic segmentation of the picture. then you'll know which pixels are "table" and you can select those from the point cloud.